# Question about conservative vector fields.

Tags: vector-fields, line-integrals

I don't understand how is this even possible(the question stated below), as in a previously stated theorem that the $\oint\mathbf F\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$ of conservative field vector is zero. So what is the difference between these two examples

> If $\mathbf F(x,y)=\frac{-y i+x j}{x^2+y^2}$, show that $\oint\mathbf F\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=2\pi$ for every positively oriented simple closed path that encloses the origin.

Comment: What is the definition of a conservative vector field? Also, what is the precise statement of the theorem you are referencing?

Comment: That vector field $F$ is not defined at the origin.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I was referring to these three theorems[ https://imgur.com/a/xOOaYKj ] But I overlooked the fact that it has to be continuous.

Comment: @littleO Yes, thanks!

Comment: @MahmoudRagab Actually the vector field is continuously differentiable and irrotational over the punctured plane; the problem is that the punctured plane is not *simply connected* (the crucial hypothesis of your Theorem 6), i.e., you can't shrink a loop around the origin to a point without passing through the puncture. This is why Theorem 6 (aka the Poincaré lemma) fails here.

Comment: @AlexProvost It wasn't explained thoroughly what is meant by simply-connected region, but yeah, I have just read about the Poincaré lemma and got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral $\oint F\cdot dr$ being zero for any closed path is the *definition* of a conservative field. (At least it is in my book; I would find anything else strange, as that integral captures the notion of conservation.)

On the other hand, an irrotational vector field (i.e. a vector field with no curl) can fail to be conservative if it has points where it's not defined. If a vector field is defined, continuous and irrotational on the *whole plane* (or more generally on a simply connected domain), then it is conservative. In this case, however, the origin is a problem point, obstructing our field from being conservative.

Answer (score 0):

Well, quite simply: your given vector field is not conservative. (Proof: exactly the fact that $\oint_{S^1} F \cdot dr = 2\pi$, as you mention.) Heuristically, a potential function would be something like $f(x,y) = \arctan(y/x)$, which is ill-defined over an entire line.

Comment: Yes, I got it. thanks!